# Programming Puzzles and Taco Truck

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Programming Puzzles & Code Golf has opened a [taco truck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_truck)! The word is out and now users from all over the Stack Exchange network are coming to try our tasty, authentic ASCII [tacos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taco). We need your help to ensure that everyone gets their orders in a timely manner. There isn't a whole lot of room inside food trucks, so you'll need your code to be as short as possible.

Now for some on-the-job training.

### Your job

Write a full program that reads an order from STDIN or a function that gets a single string order as input. Tacos are printed to STDOUT, made to order.

### Taking orders

Customers will give you their orders via STDIN or function argument. Orders will be in the form of a comma-delimited list of desired toppings. The order in which the toppings are given dictates the order in which they appear in the taco, with the first listed topping on the bottom and the last on the top. Here's what we keep in stock:

- Beans
- Rice
- Veggies
- Lettuce
- Guacamole
- Sour cream
- Salsa

Customers may order as few as 1 topping but no more than 5 toppings. Toppings need not be distinct.

You may assume that the customers are familiar with the menu before ordering and thus all orders will only contain ingredients that we stock. That is, the input will always be valid.

### Serving tacos

Customers demand their tacos be printed to STDOUT. They're fine with some leading or trailing whitespace in their food.

Market research shows that everyone wants to eat tacos as words, and words in all caps are much more flavorful. Thus we will list toppings in ALL CAPS with no spaces.

In the interest of artsy presentation, we can't just plop stuff in a tortilla and call it good, we have to gently lay toppings left to right, wrapping and repeating as needed. Each topping gets a minimum of 2 lines to itself. This will all become clearer once we inspect the sample platter.

### Sample platter

Let's take a look at some sample orders.

The customer orders: `Beans,Veggies,Rice,Lettuce,Sour Cream`

We deliver:

```
   SOUR
  CREAMS
T LETTUC L
O ELETTU I
R RICERI T
T CERICE R
I VEGGIE O
L SVEGGI T
L BEANSB A
 A EANS L
  TORTIL
```

Looks pretty tasty, right? The toppings wrap after 6 characters to a new line and are repeated to fill 2 lines each, truncated to 12 characters. The first ingredient gets 6 characters on its top line but only 4 on its second line. This ensures that it fits in the fold of the tortilla. Similarly, the last ingredient always gets 4 characters on its top line and 6 on its second.

What happens if a customer orders two of the same topping in a row? Keep wrapping that ingredient for all consecutive lines of that ingredient.

The customer orders: `Lettuce,Lettuce,Lettuce,Salsa`

We deliver:

```
T  SALS  L
O ASALSA I
R LETTUC T
T ELETTU R
I CELETT O
L UCELET T
L TUCELE A
 A TTUC L
  TORTIL
```

The customer orders: `Guacamole`

```
T        L
O        I
R        T
T        R
I        O
L  GUAC  T
L AMOLEG A
 A UACA L
  TORTIL
```

Only one ingredient? Give 4 extra characters' worth on the top.

### Employees of the month

```js
var QUESTION_ID=65888,OVERRIDE_USER=20469;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

---

Happy cooking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>269</s> 263 bytes

```js
x=>eval('x=x.split`,`;p=o="";for(i=10;i--;){t=x[1]?x[i/2|0]:x[i>2|0];t!=p?r=(n=0,t?t.replace(s=" ",""):s).toUpperCase().repeat(99):0;m=r.slice(n,n+=p&&i?6:4);p&&i?0:m=s+m+s;p=t;o+=(i>7?t?s+s+m:"":i?"TORTILL"[7-i]+s+m+s+"LITROTA"[7-i]:` A${m}L`)+`\n`}')+"  TORTIL"
```

### Explanation

```js
x=>
  eval('                                          // use eval to save writin return and {}
    x=x.split`,`;                                 // convert ingredients to an array
    p=                                            // p = previous ingredient
      o="";                                       // o = output text
    for(i=10;i--;){                               // loop from top to bottom of taco
      t=x[1]?x[i/2|0]                             // t = ingredient text
        :x[i>2|0];                                // start a line early if 1 ingredient
      t!=p?r=                                     // r = repeated ingredient text
        (n=0,                                     // n = current index in repeated text
        t?t.replace(s=" ",""):s)                  // get the ingredient (or space)
        .toUpperCase().repeat(99):0;              // upper-case and repeat the ingredient
      m=r.slice(n,n+=p&&i?6:4);p&&i?0:m=s+m+s;    // m = text in the middle of the taco
      p=t;                                        // set p to current ingredient

      // Add the appropriate output
      o+=(i>7?t?s+s+m:"":i?"TORTILL"[7-i]+s+m+s+"LITROTA"[7-i]:` A${m}L`)+`\n`

    }                                             // implicit: eval returns o
  ')+"  TORTIL"                                   // return the output text
```

### Test

```js
var solution = x=>eval('x=x.split`,`;p=o="";for(i=10;i--;){t=x[1]?x[i/2|0]:x[i>2|0];t!=p?r=(n=0,t?t.replace(s=" ",""):s).toUpperCase().repeat(99):0;m=r.slice(n,n+=p&&i?6:4);p&&i?0:m=s+m+s;p=t;o+=(i>7?t?s+s+m:"":i?"TORTILL"[7-i]+s+m+s+"LITROTA"[7-i]:` A${m}L`)+`\n`}')+"  TORTIL"
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="Beans,Veggies,Rice,Lettuce,Sour Cream" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: As the shortest answer at the end of the bounty period, you receive the bounty of +50! And as the shortest of the two posted answers a week after the question was posted, you win the coveted check mark. Nice work and thanks for participating! :)

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3, 475 bytes

```python
n=range
s=input().upper().replace(" ","").split(",")[::-1]
s=sum(zip(s,s),tuple())
t=""
p=0
l=len(s)
if l==2:q=s[0];s=[q,q,q];l=3
r=[]
e=" "
f=e*4
d=[f," AL ","L  A","L  T","I  O","T  R","R  T","O  I","T  L",f,f]
for i in n(l):
 h=s[i]
 c=6
 a=""
 if i==0 or i==l-1:c=4
 if t!=h:
  p=0
  t=h
 for x in n(0,c):
  a+=h[p]
  p+=1
  if p==len(h):
   p=0
 if c==4:a=e+a+e
 r+=[a]
r=["TORTIL"]+r[::-1]
for i in n(0,11):
 y=10-i
 x=d[y]
 m=e*6
 if y<=l:m=r[y]
 print(x[:2]+m+x[2:])
```

It's probably way too long, but I may as well post something!

Comment: I think you can replace `r=(r+["TORTIL"])[::-1]` with `r=["TORTIL"]+r[::-1]`. `range(0,l)` can also be `range(l)`.

Comment: 1. Stack Exchange replaces tabs with four spaces, so it's hard to verify your score as it is. After re-replacing them, I count 482. 2. You can save on whitespace by putting, e.g., `if l==2:q=s[0];s=[q,q,q];l=3` on a single line. 3. `n(l)` does the same as `n(0,l)`.

Comment: @Dennis is there something I can do about #1?

Comment: You could just use a single space instead of a tab. Python 3 doesn't allow mixing them anyway.

Comment: Okay, I've taken your suggestions and made it slightly shorter.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>376</s> <s>375</s> <s>368</s> <s>363</s> 362 bytes

```ruby
->a{p='ALLITROT'.chars
s='LATORTIL'.chars
t=['  TORTIL']
c=[*a.split(?,).chunk(&:upcase)]
c.map.with_index{|x,i|n=x[1].size*2
w=x[0].tr(' ','')*9*n
[n+=i==0?1:0,w.sub!(/..../,' \0 ')]if i==c.size-1
w.chars.each_slice(6).take(n).reverse.map{|l|t=["#{p.shift||' '} #{l*''} #{s.shift||' '}"]+t}}
p.map{|x|t=[x+' '*8+s.shift]+t}
t[-2].sub! /(.{6})../,' \1'
t.join$/}
```

Still a work in progress.

(Bonus: Works with as many toppings as you want, not just 5. Mostly because I didn't see that rule at first >_<)

Ungolfed version:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def make_taco ingredients
    # These three variables make up the tortilla.
    prefixes = 'ALLITROT'.chars
    suffixes = 'LATORTIL'.chars
    taco = ['  TORTIL']
    # .chunk is a Ruby builtin that's *incredibly* useful for this challenge.
    chunks = ingredients.split(',').chunk{|x| x}.to_a
    # Loop through every chunk of equal ingredients.
    chunks.each_with_index do |ingredient, idx|
        # Get the number of lines the group of ingredients should take up.
        count = ingredient[1].length * 2
        # *9 because that's guaranteed to be enough ingredient.
        wrapped = ingredient[0].upcase.sub(' ','') * 9 * count
        # If this is the last element...
        if idx == chunks.length - 1
            # Add spaces strategically to position the top "layer."
            wrapped.sub! /..../, ' \0 '
            # If this is also the first element...
            if idx == 0
                # We need to make one more row.
                count += 1
            end
        end
        # Arrange the ingredient like so, and then for each "layer"...
        wrapped.chars.each_slice(6).take(count).reverse.each do |line|
            # Add it to the taco, along with prefixes/suffixes if they exist.
            taco.push "#{prefixes.shift || ' '} #{line * ''} " +
                "#{suffixes.shift || ' '}"
        end
    end
    # Fill in the rest of the prefixes and suffixes we didn't use.
    prefixes.each do |prefix|
        taco.push prefix + ' ' * 8 + suffixes.shift
    end
    # Fix the "offset" on the second-to-last line.
    taco[1].sub! /(.{6})../, ' \1'
    # Since we've been building the taco bottom-up, reverse, join, and return.
    taco.reverse.join("\n")
end

puts make_taco 'Beans,Veggies,Rice,Lettuce,Sour Cream'
puts
puts make_taco 'Lettuce,Lettuce,Lettuce,Salsa'
puts
puts make_taco 'Guacamole'
```